# How to reproduce a RandomForestClassifier when random_state uses RandomState

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

## Context:

I was reading the [Common Pitfalls](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/common_pitfalls.html) documentation of scikit-learn. I was surprised with the Controlling randomness section, as in my case I've always use `random_state` with and integer, to read that the estimator should use an instance of `np.random.RandomState` in the initialization of the classifier, but not on the cv split; after reading Robustness of cross-validation results section I thought: 'Ok I get it', BUT, there is a warning in the cloning section that says:

```py
from sklearn import clone
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
a = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=rng)
b = clone(a)
```

> Since a RandomState instance was passed to a, a and b are not clones in the strict sense, but rather clones in the statistical sense: a and b will still be different models, even when calling fit(X, y) on the same data. Moreover, a and b will influence each-other since they share the same internal RNG: calling a.fit will consume b’s RNG, and calling b.fit will consume a’s RNG, since they are the same. This bit is true for any estimators that share a random_state parameter; it is not specific to clones.

> If an integer were passed, a and b would be exact clones and they would not influence each other
> Warning Even though clone is rarely used in user code, it is called pervasively throughout scikit-learn codebase: in particular, most meta-estimators that accept non-fitted estimators call clone internally (GridSearchCV, StackingClassifier, CalibratedClassifierCV, etc.).

## Question

If I am on the developing phase of a project and trying to identify which model(s) works best with lets say a GridSearchCV how can I get the `random_state` value of my model so I can use it in production?

At first I thoght lets use in the grid `random_state`, but the Robustness of cross-validation results section writes:

> Passing instances leads to more robust CV results, and makes the comparison between various algorithms fairer. It also helps limiting the temptation to treat the estimator’s RNG as a hyper-parameter that can be tuned.

Answer (score 1):

The `random_state` parameter is really intended for deterministic reproducibility & is especially useful when developing more complex pipelines.

GridSearchCV is used to find the best settings for your learning **procedure**. I emphasize procedure, because the cross-validation aspect is to get statistical results based on an estimate rather than an actual concrete model. Your RandomForest classifier & cross-validation like many techniques in machine learning rely on entropy/randomness to fairly approximate things. `random_state` should **NOT** be treated as a hyper-parameter else you are metric climbing on noise.

Once you know the optimal settings that statistically yield a good model beyond random chance, you want to re-apply the procedure to derive your production model. Note that the metric performance of this model will be bounded within (but not identical to) what grid-search estimated. Specifying `random_state` for the production model is bogus.

Here is a valid way to do things with/out specifying the random seeds:

```py
# define your procedure as you wish. random_state is optional
# good for testing, irrelevant for predicting.
my_pipeline = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, ..)

# search parameter space & then refit another model with your 
# procedure on the discovered parameters.
optimal = GridSearchCV(my_pipeline, params, refit=True, ...)
optimal.fit(train_X, train_y)

# get the new model trained with the best found parameters,
# rather than best performing model of the cross-validation!!
prod_model = optimal.best_estimator_
```

Comment: I just read your explanation and I feel so dummy. Thank you @eliangius.

Answer (score 1):

The warning stems from using the random number generator object rather than the random seed integer.

When you use the generator, subsequent calls to it, will produce different seeds in the random sequence. This means that since the clones share the same generator sequence the order of operations, rate at which each gets invoked etc is implicitly coupled & thus produce different but statistically equivalent objects. Using random integer seeds is safe.